# The GetVaryByCustomString method is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outputcache, varybyparam

The GetVaryByCustomString method is not fired when I place a breakpoint in it.

The action I want to cache depending on the language the user selected:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "24HoursCache", VaryByCustom = "lang")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    ...
}
```

The cache profile in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        ...
        <caching>
            <outputCacheSettings>
                <outputCacheProfiles>
                    <clear />
                    <add name="24HoursCache" duration="86400" location="Client" varyByParam="none" />
                </outputCacheProfiles>
            </outputCacheSettings>
        </caching>
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

And in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string value)
{
    if (value.ToLower() == "lang")
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, value);
}
```

Any help would  be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually location must be set to "Server", and not "Client".

```
<configuration>
        ...
        <system.web>
            ...
            <caching>
                <outputCacheSettings>
                    <outputCacheProfiles>
                        <clear />
                        <add name="24HoursCache" duration="86400" location="Server" varyByParam="none" />
                    </outputCacheProfiles>
                </outputCacheSettings>
            </caching>
        </system.web>
        ...
    </configuration>
```

And it works, phew!